# Update SQL query - Set values to PHP string variable

Tags: php, sql, string, variables, sql-update

This is probably a very trivial question but I've been struggling with it for a while and also tried finding answers online and still getting errors.

Trying to write a simple UPDATE query for a PHP/MySql form:

```
  $sql="UPDATE mytable SET numericValue = '".$someid."', description =  '".$sometext."' WHERE id='".$myid."' ";
```

Whilst all numeric values are being passed and updated fine, I can't get the description right. The description column  is a VARCHAR and $sometext is a string and I cant get it escaped / wrapped with quotes correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of sprintf, it avoids string confusion by providing placeholders (%d for decimals, %s for strings). See the [manual](http://php.net/sprintf) for more.

```
$sql= sprintf("UPDATE mytable SET numericValue = %d, description = '%s' WHERE id = %d", $someid, $sometext, $myid);
```

If $someText is coming from GET/POST/.. you should wrap a mysql_real_escape_string() around it to prevent SQL injection (or use PDO prepared statements).

Comment: sprintf() is an ugly method if it's a complex query with lots of values to insert. Far too easy to mis-place parameters. better to massage the values before building the string and then build it "traditionally", or better yet, yes, use PDO.

Comment: I did try sprintf method, however still not successful.  Record is being updated but only the numeric values change - no sql errors but VARCHAR doesn't get updated

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="UPDATE mytable SET numericValue = '$someid' , description = '$sometext' WHERE id='$myid' ";
```

I think you have to worry about sql injection.